# How to using "Powershell" connect-AzureAd using a token?

Tags: powershell

I have tried the below, I am able to open the session but any command I want to run there after. I get "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

Where or what privileges should I add to my app or is my code in correct.

```
        $clientId = "appid"  
        $clientSecret = "secter"  
        $tenantName = "companydomain/tenant"  
        $tokenBody = @{  
           Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"  
           Scope         = "https://graph.windows.net/.default"  
           Client_Id     = $clientId  
           Client_Secret = $clientSecret  
        
        }   
        $AADTokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $tokenBody -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    
    $tokenBody = @{  
       Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"  
       Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"  
       Client_Id     = $clientId  
       Client_Secret = $clientSecret  
    
    }   
    $graphTokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $tokenBody -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Connect-AzureAD -TenantId 'tenantid' -AadAccessToken $AADTokenResponse.access_token -MsAccessToken $graphTokenResponse.access_token -AccountId "userid"

Get-AzureADTenantDetail
Get-AzureADTenantDetail : Error occurred while executing GetTenantDetails 
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
RequestId: 3f0689b8-220b-4c13-869a-0b34530435fe
DateTimeStamp: Sun, 22 Aug 2021 11:48:44 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureADTenantDetail
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADTenantDetail], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetTenantDetails
```

Comment: Did you grant your app the api permission to connect  as the application on behalf of the org ? ... I have a somewhat different enough scenario that I won't post it as a answer for that reason  where I connect as myself (the user) or a service principal and from there, generate an AAD token. I use solely `https://graph.windows.net` along with the `-AadAccessToken`.  I never tried with App client / Secret though but I don't use the `-MsAccessToken` part  at all.

Comment: Thank you for the replay yes I have added rights : "User.Read.All","Directory.ReadWrite.All","User.ReadWrite.All","Reports.Read.All",     "CallRecords.Read.All", "Calls.AccessMedia.All","Domain.ReadWrite.All","application_access","application_access_custom_sba_appliance","AppCatalog.ReadWrite.All""Group.ReadWrite.All".                                                                               
When using this command I get the same issue :  "Connect-AzureAD -AccountId        "user@company.com" -AadAccessToken $ADTokenResponse.access_token"